# Electron in magnetic field and slowly varying potential $V(x)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

What are the approximation methods for the spectrum and wavefunctions of a 2D electron in a perpendicular magnetic field $B$ and a scalar potential $V(x)$ which is slowly varying on the scale of the magnetic length $\ell_B = \hbar/\sqrt{eB}$? For concreteness

$$H = (\mathbf{p}-e\mathbf{A})^2/2m + V(x,y)$$
where $\mathbf{A} = (B/2)(-y,x,0)$. Assume the potential has amplitude $V_0$ (e.g. $V(x,y) = V_0(\cos(Qx)+\cos(Qy))$ and we may be in the strong potential regime $V_0 > \omega_c = eB/m$.

We cannot apply perturbation theory in $V_0/\omega_c$. In real space, I imagine we can think of the energy eigenstates near energy $E_0$ as wavefunctions of width $\ell_B$ which follow the constant energy contours $V(x) = E_0$. I don't know if this can be made precise.

I am ultimately interested in the question of whether the wavefunctions are extended or localized in the case when $V(x,y)$ is quasiperiodic.

Comment: This is the same as the Hofstadter's butterfly problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't assume $V(x,y)$ has any translation symmetry.

Comment: Ok. In the example of $V(x,y)$ you gave, it is periodic. Maybe then you need to solve the exact Hamiltonian numerically. Or, you may solve the Landau level problem 'locally', assuming $V(x,y)=E_0$, and put in the space dependence of $E_0$ in the final result.